# Highlight the selected row in data list

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a DataList on ym web page, from which a user can choose a certain option within the DataList row.

I use the `ItemCommand` of DataList for this. Actually, I want to highlight the selected row when the user clicks on the item in the row.

```
<ItemTemplate>
        <tr>
        <td style="text-align:center"><asp:LinkButton ID="Item" Text='<%#Eval("Item")%>' CommandName="select" runat="server" /> <br /></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><asp:Label ID="lbQuery" Text='<%#Eval("Query")%>' runat="server" /><br /> </td>
        </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
```

As shown above, the user can click on the LinkButton to choose an item. How do I highlight the corresponding row or only the cell?

Answer (score 0):

in your RowDataBound event add like this.

```
// Get the linklabel object and check for non nullity
LinkLabel lblItem = e.Item.FindControl("Item") as LinkLabel

if(lblitem !=null)
{
// add properties to it 
lblItem.Attributes.Add("onclick", "this.style.background='#eeff00'");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

on Item command

```
string[] str = e.CommandArgument.ToString().Split(';');
int index = Convert.ToInt32(str[2]); // ur item selected index
DataListItemCollection xx = DataList1.Items;
int count = 0;
foreach (DataListItem x in xx)
{
  if (count == index)
    {
      (x.FindControl("Item") as LinkButton).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
      (x.FindControl("Item") as LinkButton).BorderWidth = 1;
    }
  else
    {
      (x.FindControl("Item") as LinkButton).BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.White;
      (x.FindControl("Item") as LinkButton).BorderWidth = 0;

    }
 count = count + 1;
}
```